# Property in state becomes undefined within action creators

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm making an app where different users can add their own plants/flowers.
The flowerlist contains the users flowers and loads these items upon mounting.

```
class flowerList extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getFlowers();
}
```

To send the correct GET request to the backend I need to have the currently logged in user's ID.
This is what the called action creator looks like:

```
export const getFlowers = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
dispatch(setFlowersLoading());
axios
    .get(`/api/users/${getState().auth.user.id}/flowers`)
    .then((res) =>
        dispatch({
            type    : GET_FLOWERS,
            payload : res.data
        })
    )
    .catch((err) => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status)));
};
```

However, this doesn't work very well. It only works when coming directly from signing in. If I refresh the page, the app crashes with the error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null". When writing the POST requests in a similar fashion it doesn't work well either, so I guess there must be a better way to access the state. I'd really appreciate any help in getting this to work.

Comment: Can you try adding getState().auth.user.id to a variable first: 
`const userId =  getState().auth.user.id`
`console.log(userId)` => to check from console if userId is coming properly
then use it in the axios.get :
`get(`/api/users/${userId}/flowers`)`

Comment: I tried it but I get the same results. When I come from logging in, it works (at least initally). It loads the correct user and the console logs the correct Id. But when I refresh the page it crashes with the same error of the Id being null.

Answer (score 0):

When you login, you should set local storage to keep the users info something like these:

```
const setAuthorizationHeader = token => {
  const Token = `Bearer ${token}`;
  localStorage.setItem("Token", Token);
  axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = Token;
};
```

you can add it to your user login action, after `then()`, when the login is successful, here is an example, I assume you handle the token in the backend, so after successful login, it sends the token with a respond(res.data):

```
export const loginUser = (userData) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:5000/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);    
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response
      });
    });
};
```

Afterwards,  put these to your app.js:

```
const token = localStorage.Token;
if (token) {
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
  if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());
    window.location.href = "/login";
  } else {
    store.dispatch({ type: SET_AUTHENTICATED_USER });
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
    store.dispatch(getUserData(decodedToken));
  }
}
```

Here I used jwtDecode because I am using JWT to crypt my users' info and store it to the localStorage, these codes provide to look for Token in localStorage after refreshing the page. If the user logged in, there is the token and so the app will not crash